# Wpf send layout object not by button or textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, prism

I've got a little bit problem with sending my layout object. I'm trying to create an WPF app in style like a chrome with draggable cards. To do this, I'm using OpenControls.Wpf library + Prism + MahApps.Metro

**Layout declarated in main xaml view**

```
<dockManager:LayoutManager x:Name="_layoutManager" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                                           DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}" ToolsSource="{Binding Tools}" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" UseLayoutRounding="False"
                                           Margin="0,-4,0,0">

                    <dockManager:LayoutManager.Theme>
                        <themes:ModernTheme/>
                    </dockManager:LayoutManager.Theme>
                    <dockManager:LayoutManager.DocumentTemplates>

                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type usViewModel:UsersModule_ViewModel}" >
                            <usViews:UsersModule_View x:Name="UsersModuleModule" Margin="4"/>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </dockManager:LayoutManager.DocumentTemplates>
</dockManager:LayoutManager>
```

**Buttons to open projects in card in the same xaml file**

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Style="{StaticResource ButtonMore}" Content="Users" 
         Command="{Binding LoadModule1Command}" 
         CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_layoutManager}" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,80,24,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208" Height="40"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

By the DelegateCommand { get; private set; } in my module, through the button CommandParameter is sending an layoutManager object. I need to get that object, but without click any button or textbox.

So my main question:
Is it possible, to send an object without any buttons or is it possible to programmatically call of the click event in WPF.

I've search something about that problem, but did not find any solution.

Comment: you can simply expose `_layoutManager` as property and then bind it (one way or onetime) to some property in VM ... is it good idea? well .... you wana expose UI element to VM anyway ...

Comment: Can't you bind documentssource to an observablecollection of viewmodels.  Template them out into cards and manipulate the observablecollection?